# How to display an array of object with NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object

what is the solution to display an array of object with "NSLog".

I can display it with my TableView with :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell2"];
        DataOrder *bug = [[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyBasicCell2";
        CustomCellFinalView *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        if (!Cell) {
            Cell = [[CustomCellFinalView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        Cell.NomProduit.text = bug.product;
        Cell.Quantite.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f €", bug.price];
        Cell.Prix.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"X %d  ", bug.quantite];

        return Cell;
        return cell;    
}
```

When I try in my `ViewDidLoad:` method this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau]);
```

I obtain in my target output:

```
(
    "<DataOrder: 0x15d5d980>",
    "<DataOrder: 0x15de1aa0>"
)
```

Thank you very much for your futur help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
for ( DataOrder *bug in [[ArrayBuying instance] tableau] ) 
{
    NSLog(@"Product:- %@ Price:-%@", bug.product, bug.price);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can implement `- (NSString *)description` method in class DataOrder.

NSLog will show the return value of description method of a instance if the description is available.

Check out the document of NSObject protocol https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

With description method implemented, you can print object easier afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Write `- (NSString*) description` method in DataOrder class.

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",myData1,myData2];
}

 NSLog(@"%@",[[[ArrayBuying instance] tableau] descriptionWithLocale:nil indent:1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` calls object's `description` method in order to print it. If you don't implement this method for your class (`DataOrder` in this case), it will call `NSObject's` default implementation which only prints the object's address.