# ios sqllite Return data not able to show

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am new to iOS , I am using SQLite and I've succeeded inserting data in database, but when I try to get data and NSLog it, I get:   `<Person: 0x10f2242e0>`

What should I do? How to get data?

Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray*)getPersons
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SleepCycle&time.db"];

    // Check to see if the database file already exists
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // Open the database and store the handle as a data member
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    }




    // Allocate a persons array
    NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Create the query statement to get all persons
    NSString *queryStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID, ADATE, STIME, ETIME ,PER,TOTALTIME,TOTALTIMEMINUTE FROM PERSON"];

    // Prepare the query for execution
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [queryStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Iterate over all returned rows
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            // Get associated address of the current person row
            int personID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);



            // Create a new person and add it to the array

            Person *person = [[Person alloc]GetAllData:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]
                                        andStime:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]
                                        andEtime:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]
                                         andper:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)]
                              andtotaltime:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)]
                              andtotaltimeMinute:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)]
                                             andIdd:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] ];



            // try for id
           /* Person *person = [[Person alloc]Getdata:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]
                                                  andLastName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]
                                                  andBirthday:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)]
                                         andAddress:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)]
                                             andIdd:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] ];
            */
            [persons addObject:person];


        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    // Return the persons array ----------------------------

    NSLog(@"%@",persons);

    return persons;
}
```

The last line before `return persons;` is where I print data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Persons` is an array of object in your code, and it contains various `person` objects in it; therefore `NSLog`ing it, you'll only see the memory address of the object. If you want to see the properties of individual `person` objects in your array, you need to do something like:

```
NSLog(@"Person 1:, %@", [persons objectAtIndex:0].lastName); 
//Based on Objective-C naming conventions you better use "lastName" rather than "LastName", etc.
```

You can use a for loop to go through all the items in your array and pring their properties.

Search and read the related documentations, and have a look at some other similar questions and answers in this regards:
[How to display an array of object with NSLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328281/how-to-display-an-array-of-object-with-nslog) or
[Dumping contents of Array Obj-c to consoler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071124/dumping-contents-of-array-obj-c-to-consoler).